# How is `[e | x <- xs; y <- ys; ...] = concat[[e | y <- ys; ...] | x <- xs]`

Tags: javascript, haskell, functional-programming, list-comprehension

I am reading "Introduction to Functional Programming First Edition".
I came about a rule to translate comprehension as,

```
[e | x <- xs; y <- ys; ...] = concat[[e | y <- ys; ...] | x <- xs]
```

I don't understand concat here. `concat` takes multiple lists but here I see only one.

I read `[[e | y <- ys; ...] | x <- xs]` as

```
for(x in xs){
 for(y in ys){
  someList.push(e)
 }
}
```

Maybe I am reading it wrong or `|` holds some special meaning here.

Please help.

Comment: `concat :: [[a]] -> [a]`. `concat[[e | y <- ys; ...] | x <- xs]` --- here you get a list of lists, that is then unfolded to a flat list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[e | y <- ys; ...] | x <- xs]` translated to your pseudo-language would be:

```
for (x in xs) {
    tmp = []
    for (y in ys) {
        tmp.push(e)
    }

    someList.push(tmp)
}
```

And you could read the `[[e | y <- ys; ...] | x <- xs]` expression as: "For every `x` in `xs` produce a list that consists of `e` for every `y` in `ys`".

`concat` has the following signature: `concat :: [[a]] -> [a]`

So it unfolds the folded structures.

Hence `concat [[1,2,3],[4,5]]` => `[1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: @Abhishek Javascript's `concat` is `(++)` in Haskell, which has the type `[a] -> [a] -> [a]`. However, in JS arrays don't have to be homogeneous, of course.